# DataRow: why can't I just access .Date on a DateTime type column?

Tags: c#

I have a DataTable contains a ["TimeLineFrom"] column which is `System.DateTime`.

so I want to iterate like this

```
foreach (DataRow dr in myDataTable)
{
    if (dr["TimeLineFrom"].Date > System.DateTime.Now)
    ...
}
```

> error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no
> accessible extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type
> 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
> assembly reference?)

below is from Immediate window:

```
? dr["TimeLineFrom"].Date()
error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no accessible extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

? dr["TimeLineFrom"].Date
error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no accessible extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

? dr["TimeLineFrom"]
{1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM}
    Date: {1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 1
    DayOfWeek: Friday
    DayOfYear: 1
    Hour: 0
    Kind: Unspecified
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 0
    Month: 1
    Second: 0
    Ticks: 635872032000000000
    TimeOfDay: {00:00:00}
    Year: 2016
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core `DataRow` class doesn't know in advance what kind of items will be in each field, and therefore the **compile-time** type for an column lookup is just `Object`. Since you *know* you have a `DateTime`, and you *know* it's not null/DBNull, you can **cast** the value to do what you need:

```
if ((DateTime)(dr["TimeLineFrom"]).Date > System.DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: add one more parenthesis `if (  ((DateTime)(dr["TimeLineFrom"])).Date > System.DateTime.Now)` works

Answer (score 1):

Because `DataRow["name"]` return instance of the `object` type.
You should cast returned value to expected type.

Use built-in extension methods

```
var date = dataRow.Field<DateTime>("TimeLineFrom").Date;
```

For possible `DbNull` values cast value into nullable type

```
var date = dataRow.Field<DateTime?>("TimeLineFrom").GetValueOrDefault();
// returns DateTime.Min for null
```